# Getting top most sold items from millions of transactional data

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

Suppose I have an online store application that contains millions of items that are maintained by the application. The application is so famous that millions of items get sold for each hour. I store all this information in a database, say Oracle DB.

Now if I want to show the top 5 items sold in the last 1 Hour then I can write a query something like :

- Get the list of products that were sold in last 1 Hour.
- Find the count of each product from above result and order by that count value, then display the top 5 records.

This seems to be a working query, but the problem is, for each 1 Hour if I am having millions of items sold then running this query against the table that contains all the transactional information will definitely hit performance issues. How can we fix such issues? Are there any other way of implementing it.

Comment: Please show us the query, the table definitions (including all indexes) and the execution plan. http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

Comment: This is just an assumption to understand how the online shopping applications works.

Comment: We can't help you tune a query that you don't show to us. We are not mind readers nor do we have a crystal ball.

Comment: Thanks for taking time in responding for my post. Based on the post details I have mentioned here, my point is we cannot query directly on a database table that contains the transactional information which has so many millions of records. So I wanted to know if there is any alternate approach followed in such cases.

Comment: We are querying several tables with > 15 million rows that are constantly being updated on a regular basis in our production environments. I don't understand where your problem is. This is what relational DBMS are built for. With the right table design and indexing this is no problem.

Comment: Given that this is a hypothetical question you might want to ask it over on http://cs.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow is a place to ask practical questions relating to "how do I fix this problem I've got right now".

Answer (score 3):

As a note, Amazon at its peak on Cyber Monday is selling a bit over a million items per hour.  You must have access to an incredible data store.

Partitioning is definitely one solution, but it can be a little complicated.  When you say "the last hour" that can go over a partitioning boundary.  Not a big deal, but it would mean accessing multiple partitions for each query.

Even one million items and hour is just a few hundred items per second.  This *might* give you enough leeway to add a trigger (or probably logic to an existing trigger) that would maintain a summary table of what you are looking for.

I offer this as food-for-thought.

I doubt that you are actually querying the real operational system.  My guess is that any environment that is handling even a dozen sales per second is *not* going to have such queries running on the operational system.  The architecture is more likely a feed into a decision support system.  And, that gives you the leeway to implement an additional summary table as data goes into the system.  This is not question of creating triggers on a load.  It is, instead, a question of loading detailed data into one table and summary information into another table, based on how the information is being passed from the original operation system to the decision support system.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try the [partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm).

E.g. you can split the data for each month/week/whatever into different partitions using maybe [range partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#i468016) and then for the last hour it is quite easy to run the query only for a specific, last partition. See [partitioning-wise joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#I1050102) to learn more about it.

Of course, you'll need to perform some specific implementation steps, but every war can require some sacrifice...

Comment: Thaks Simon for responding. Also is there any alternate solution that is followed in such cases, like caching etc

Comment: I am not sure caching will work: you change your table to often. The only additional ability I see is a materialized view, but partitions look much more tasty. Anyway you should try first of all if there is a problem with performance: maybe it will work as it is with proper indices. Don't try to solve performance problems if they are not yet presented. But it is nice that you think about the way back now, and with partitions you have it!